# Should questions containing code that have clearly not even been run through a compiler be entertained?

Tags: discussion

I have recently come upon [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20906649/how-to-print-a-char-array-in-c-with-printf) which surprisingly has more upvotes than downvotes.

It seems that the OP could have been expected at the very least to run their code through the compiler and describe a desired behavior before posting such a question, but there are 6 answers on that question.

How do others feel about such questions on SO?

Comment: Six answers from 190k of rep. I don't see how the question is going to help anyone else. If one typo is enough to close a question as no use to anyone except the answer, systemic typos should get the same treatment, but even faster.

Comment: Not only should the question be closed, but this particular question should also be deleted.  The question itself, which is a terrible example of what Stack Overflow question should look like, received 13 upvotes, and the *asker* is getting a net +65 rep as of this comment.

Comment: @nhgrif Well, Meta sure took care of that.

Comment: Downvote and move on. Sadly, people obssessed with game points on this site will spoonfeed the person regardless.

Comment: @NewWorld: That's a pessimistic view, I prefer to think that people are nice and want to help, and do not realize that spoon-feeding does not help (on the mid/long term).

Answer (score -3):

What we need is a canonical question/answer for setting up syntax checking, and error reporting where appropirate.

Often commenters say something about switching on `E_ALL` for apache configs, for example; but it would perhaps be a better modal to post a question/answer in the comments that actually explained ...

- What is error reporting and why it's important
- How to switch on error reporting for popular platforms
- Why using a syntax checker (or even syntax highlighting) solves a lot of issues

and so on.

This could also lead to many a google search falling on this question rather than any of the pletherer of specific questions around Stack Overflow on syntax errors.

Comment: This is unrelated to the original post, probably misplaced.

Comment: We already have [a page](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) about how to ask a good question. Expanding that to briefly mention things like including the error messages you're getting, avoiding generic statements like "doesn't work" without then elaborating, etc. would be a good idea. If they don't know how to do something with their platform then finding that information should be left for them to do. If, after all of that, they still ask a bad question, downvote to oblivion because they deserve it.

Comment: @Anthony the \[ask\] page already links to [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @CodeCaster It does, but the way the first page is phrased suggests that's only for questions about code - if you're trying to set up a web server you're probably going to skip the entire section on code examples, and not click through to the MCVE page. There are plenty of bad, non-code questions that would benefit from being told to be more specific than "It doesn't work." and to include error messages so moving it on to the how-to-ask page might be beneficial.

Comment: @Anthony oh yeah, I've been closing _"I get a 500 server error!"_ as duplicate of _"How to enable detailed error reporting on IIS"_ questions all the like. Perhaps some FAQ page like _"How to enable error reporting"_ might be welcome.

Comment: The point is that there are many questions on SO that are caused by programmers who don't understand error checking - whether they have a good MCVE question or not. If we had a question to direct these people to, perhaps in addition to giving them an answer if appropriate, then it would avoid a lot of repetition and often people need more than you can fit in a comment.